# Theta-Model: two different (but equivalent?) descriptions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The [theta-model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_model) is usually referred to as the equation
$$
\theta_t=1-\cos\theta+(1+\cos\theta)I(t),~\theta\in S^1~~(1)
$$

I have read that sometimes the scalar phase equation
$$
\theta_t=\theta_{xx}+\cos\theta-1-\mu.~~~(2)
$$

is also called the theta-model; so is there any connection between both equations?

Can't see one but have a conjecture:

I guess that equation (2) undergoes a saddle-node bifurcation at $\mu=0$; interpreting (2) as happening on $S^1=\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, this should be a SNIC bifurcation (Saddle-node on a limit cycle bifurcation). And as far as I know, equation (1) is the normal form for systems undergoing such a bifurcation. Hence, if I am right, it should be possible to transform (2) into (1) (in some neighborhood of the bifurcation point).

So, it would be interesting to know whether (2) indeed undergoes a saddle-node bifurcation at $\mu=0$ and if there is a transformation from (2) to (1) and from (1) to (2), respectively.

---

For equation (2), for $\mu=0$, $\theta(t,x)\equiv 0$ is a spatially homogeneous equilibrium, isn't it? Putting $f(\theta;\mu)=\cos\theta-1-\mu$, we should have $\frac{1}{2}f_{\theta\theta}(0;0)\neq 0$ as well as $f_{\mu}(0;0)\neq 0$; hence for $\theta_t=f(\theta;\mu)$ we should have a saddle-node bifurcation at $\mu=0$. But does this also hold for $\theta_t=\theta_{xx}+f(\theta;\mu)$?

Comment: Just curious: in what sense do you understand that (2) undergoes saddle-node bifurcation?

Comment: @Evgeny In a paper, they consider $u_t=Du_{xx}+f(u;\mu)$ with $u=u(t,x)\in\mathbb{R}^N, D>0$ a diagonal positive diffusion matrix, and $f$ a smooth nonlinearity, depending on the parameter $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, they assume that this equation undergoes a generic, stable saddle-node bifurcation and define this assumption by the following three aspects: (1) $f(0;0)=0$, and $\lambda=0$ is an algebraically simple eigenvalue of $\partial_u f(0;0)$ with eigenvector $e_0$ and adjoint eigenvector $e_0^*$, normalized so that $e_0^*\cdot e_0=1$. (2) and (3) in the next comment.

Comment: (2) $e_0^*\cdot\partial_{\mu} f(0;0)\neq 0, e_0^*\cdot \partial_{uu}f(0;0)[e_0,e_0]\neq 0$ and (3)$\text{ Re spec }(-Dk^2+\partial_u f(0;0))<0$ except for an algebraically simple eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ at $k=0$ with continuation $\lambda(k)=-dk^2+O(k^4)\text{ for }d:=e_0^*\cdot De_0>0$. - To be honest, I do not understand each point. But I guess this is what I have to show for my equation, too. In my situation, it should be $N=1$ and $D=1$.

Comment: Okay. I wouldn't say that I've understood exactly what's happening here, but you answered my question. I think to understand it fully it will need the article that you're reading (also, it's always not bad to attach the link to the article if it is possible). Speaking about connection between two equations, the solutions of both are a bit different objects: univariate functions for the first equation and bivariate functions for the second. However, all solutions of the first system can be embedded as spatially homogeneous ($u_x \equiv 0$) solutions of the second.

Comment: I think I cannot link the full article since I have not the copyright.

Comment: @Evgeny I know you cannot say it since you do not have the article; but I have just seen that the assumption of the saddle-node bifurcation "concerns spatially homogeneous equilibria". Doesn't this probably mean that the assumption is only made for $u_t=f(u;\mu)$ instead of $u_t=Du_{xx}+f(u;\mu)$? Since "spatially homogeneous equilibria" sound as if no diffusion is supposed to happen.

Comment: Since it's a published research (I suppose) you can just provide a link to the journal entry :) Speaking about spatially homogeneous equilibria, I think that we are talking about the same thing now. As I've already mentioned, you can take any solution of system (1) and it will give you a solution of system (2), but it will be spatially homogeneous. You can put equilibria of system (1) into system (2). And yes, for spatially homogeneous solution there is no diffusion since $u_x \equiv 0$ leads to $u_{xx} \equiv 0$.

Comment: As for the conditions that are present in the article, I think (though it's just a hypothesis) that they provide two things: branching of spatially homogeneous solutions and some properties of this spatially homogeneous solutions w.r.t. the whole space of solutions of system (2).

Comment: Sorry, but why is a solution of (1) a solution of (2) - - so it is true that both systems are essentially the same?

Comment: Oh, I might have confused you. I've meant the following. Suppose you have some solution $\hat{u}(t)$ of $u_t = f(u)$. You can construct a solution of $u_t = Du_{xx} + f(u)$ using a formula $u(x, t) \equiv \hat{u}(t)$. According to this formula $u(x, t)$ doesn't depend on $x$, so when you plug this function into $u_t = Du_{xx} + f(u)$ diffusion term vanishes and you have equation only for $u_t$ which is obviously satisfied by $\hat{u}(t)$. I've messed the notation, sorry.

Comment: But that doesn't mean that solutions of $u_t = Du_{xx} + f(u)$ and $u_t = f(u)$ are the same: in some sense (using the formula above) all solutions of $u_t = f(u)$ are contained in solutions of $u_t = Du_{xx} + f(u)$.

Comment: Ok, I got that. Nonetheless, I do not see if we really can consider (1) and (2) to be two descriptions of one and the same thing. It is confusing since my professor denotes (2) as the theta-model but nowhere else this is done. In the literature (1) is the theta-model. Therefore my questions if it possibly is the same.

Comment: When I see it right, for $\mu=0$, (2) has spatially homogeneous equilibium $u(x,t)\equiv 0$. Moreover, we have $\frac{1}{2}f_{uu}(0,0)\neq 0$ and $f_{\mu}(0,0)\neq 0$. Doesn't this imply that we can write (2) in form $u_t=u^2+\beta$ near the origin? And isn't the same true for $(1)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44442/discussion-between-evgeny-and-mathfemi).